# NestJS CORS blocking localhost

Tags: nestjs, superagent, connection-refused

I am trying to enable CORS to connect my nestJS API with a local react app. But it seems that CORS is blocking access from the React App.

[image: CORS ERROR]

I've tries this so far:

First attempt:

```js
 async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Second attempt:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        origin: '*',
  })
  app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

And third attempt:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        origin: 'http://localhost:3001/',
  })
  app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Nothing of that seems to work.

The React app is just a simple `superagent` call like this:

```js
 const res = sa.get(`http://localhost:3000/jokes/random`).withCredentials().end(res => console.log(res))
```

I've tried to use the `superagent` with and without the `withCredentials`.

Any idea of what is going on? thank you.

Comment: where is yours `app.listen` call?

Comment: I've updated the post, sorry.

Comment: The problem was actually with the `superagent`. Using `fetch` works fine.